# API to fetch the type of ActivityParameter which is applied to an activity in Enterprise Architect

Tags: java, enterprise-architect

I have activities on an activity diagram in Enterprise Architect for which there are some activity parameters set. The type of the Activity Parameter is set in the Parameter tab of the Properties as highlighted in the below picture. Is there any way to fetch the type of the activity parameter either through API or through EA Database.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long answer short: it's EA.

Now for the gory details. You need to look into the ClassifierGUID which can only be obtained via `t_object.classifier_guid`. Now there you will either find a "real" guid of a `t_object.ea_guid` which has been used as a classifier or (Sparx strikes again!) some crude guid like

```
{EAINT000-B653-4f3c-A010-30205D67F5F5}
```

or

```
{EASTRING-B653-4f3c-A010-30205D67F5F5}
```

You can probably guess the rest :-/ The other elementary types you can create in the GUI and see the outcome in the database.

---

I obsevered that with 13.5. Maybe, maybe, or maybe not, Sparx has made use of `EAElement.ClassifierName`/`Type` to yield some meaningful result. I just got nothing on return here.